# Opening ASPX file very slow in project with lots of master pages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

I have had a problem with Visual Studio for YEARS. Whenever I open an aspx file (the markup, not design mode, not the code behind) for the first time in a session it makes Visual Studio freeze for ~30 seconds. Closing the file and reopening is then fine until I restart Visual Studio, but during development I get these annoying 30s waits.

Having just upgraded to VS2017 and that not having magically fixed the problem (which I think I first saw in VS2013) I've put some effort into diagnosing it: copying the project, verifying that the problem still occurs, and then deleting parts until it went away.

And it turns out the cause is having a lot of master pages.

We use master pages to skin our whitelabel system for different customers, so each customer has their own master pages, and then in our PageBase we set

```
this.MasterPageFile = CustomerTheme.MasterPageFileName;
```

The master pages are nested to customise different parts of the system, which means up to 8 per customer, so there are at present more than 200 master pages in the project.

Questions:

1. Is there any way of stopping Visual Studio scan all the master pages in a project when opening an aspx page, because that's evidently what it's doing?
2. Is there a nice neat way of keeping the master pages outside of the project but still be able to work on them seamlessly that anyone knows of.

Comment: How many projects are in the solution?

Comment: 30. But I could reproduce the problem with just one Project in a solution by itself.